# Ruby Appium assert

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have to initiate a Appium webdriver using code below.

```
driver=Appium::Driver.new(desired_caps)
```

And it is working for starting an app and quits during execution.

Can any one please give examples on how to do the assert for element exists and specific value comparison?

Comment: And what is in desired_caps?

Comment: Hi , desired_caps is a serial of parameters that I set for launch mobile app(like deviceName, platformName and so on ) , and it already works.

Comment: would be great to see what else you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

You've created "driver", then next step is just

```
driver.start_driver
```

Then you can use all methods in appium ruby_lib, for example

```
driver.text('some text')
driver.button('button_name/id/text')
```

To check element exist:

```
exists { button('sign in') } ? puts('true') : puts('false')
```

You said it started then quit, it might be normal, it quits if test arrives the last step, except you add test steps or put some sleep time.

Highly recommend you to check the examples:
https://github.com/jlipps/appium-ruby-example

and also the ruby_lib doc: 
https://github.com/appium/ruby_lib/tree/master/docs